# Iterate through columns and check for conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I want to select columns that fulfill certain criteria and add them to a resulting DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('outputData.csv')

for col in df.columns:
    for index in col: #how can I do this?
        if(index > 0) #... check some conditions
```

So how can I iterate over the indices of the columns? Or is there generally a better way to do this?

**EDIT:**

The DataFrame to be read looks like:

```
col1 col2 col3 ....
1  1  4 ...
2  1  2 ...
1  0  0 ...
```

So what I basically want is extract the columns that contain the highest sum of contained values AND contain as least zeros as possible. In this case, column 1 and 3 would be preferable over column 2. Not sure yet, how I'm gonna weigh that, yet.

Comment: what are you doing with col? You realise your are just iterating over the column names and `for col in df` would do the same thing?

Comment: `for col in df.columns[1:]:` would also just get the column names ignoring the first

Comment: small example dataframe with expected results would save a lot of time here...

Comment: you're absolutely right, i see that now :)

Comment: Well, without any weighting that's `df.sum()` and `df[df==0].count()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for index, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    if index > 0:
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this question is phrased properly. When you say "columns" that fulfill certain criteria, it is unclear if you only want the data contained in that column, or if you mean you want the rows that fill the criteria based on the value of a particular column.

Here is a sample of a data frame that I have storing baseball player information. I use iPython, so the `In` and `Out` are references to the iPython shell prompts. I use the `.head(5)` method to show first five leading rows of data in the dataframe:

```html
In [45]: lahman_data.head(5)
Out[45]: 
             name handedness  height  weight    avg   HR
0       Tom Brown          R      73     170  0.000    0
1  Denny Lemaster          R      73     182  0.130    4
2       Joe Nolan          L      71     175  0.263   27
3     Denny Doyle          L      69     175  0.250   16
4   Jose Cardenal          R      70     150  0.275  138
```

If I wanted to create a new data frame, containing all the rows that met the criteria of any player that weighs > 160 pounds:

```html
In [46]: weight_gt_160 = lahman_data[lahman_data['weight'] > 160]
In [46]: weight_gt_160.head(5)
Out[46]: 
             name handedness  height  weight    avg  HR
0       Tom Brown          R      73     170  0.000   0
1  Denny Lemaster          R      73     182  0.130   4
2       Joe Nolan          L      71     175  0.263  27
3     Denny Doyle          L      69     175  0.250  16
5       Mike Ryan          R      74     205  0.193  28
```

Notice, I still have data from every column, but only the rows in the column that met my specified criteria are in the new dataframe `weight_gt_160`.

But, if you only wanted to create a dataframe that had only weight data, but also stipulated a weight greater than 160:

```html
In [48]: weight_only_gt_160 = lahman_data.weight[lahman_data['weight']> 160]
In [51]: weight_only_gt_160.head(5)
Out[51]: 
0    170
1    182
2    175
3    175
5    205
Name: weight, dtype: int64
```

I have used the syntax needed to scope the results to only the 'weight' column and nothing else.

Your questions mentions "selecting columns" but in reality you are selecting data values, within the columns, that match criteria. "Selecting columns" sounds more like you are making a general statement about the "state" of a column, and trying to craft logic to act on that generalized state.

Anyhow, hope this helps!

Comment: wow, thanks for the answer. helped a lot, although i was really just looking for the enumerate() function

Answer (score 0):

Use the [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) function to generate the index along with the column name:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('outputData.csv')

for index, column in enumerate(df.columns):
    print index, column
```

Comment: Am I missing something or is this not exactly what ozgur already answered with?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes, This is same as ozgur's solution.